# Ts-particles packag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, particles.js

I'm using ts-particles package, is there any way I can add maximum number of particles?

There are a bunch of posts saying we can add the limit by setting particles.number.value
Although it didn't work in my case. The docs as well are quite vague.